# Hello, I want a formula that counts same String from a column against the rows

Tags: excel-formula

```
Site ID Node
LLR580  PF
LLR580  MW
LLR580  Fiber
LLR580  PTCL
LLR581  PF
LLR582  PF
LLR583  MW
LLR581  MW
LLR582  PF
LLR580  PF
```

When i enter LLR580 in a column it should return:  2PF,1MW,1Fiber,1PTCL  in next column of it.

```
Siteid  Node
LLR580  2PF,1MW,1Fiber,1PTCL

And so on.
```

TIA

Comment: You should post more input/output examples because it's unclear. Also, if you tried something, you should post that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one rough and tumble suggestion on the fly: Site I.D is in Column C and Node is in D.In a third adjacent column E, combine the two columns--C1&D1. Cell A1 has the site I.D name LLR580. I used the following formula in B1 to yield the results as in your sample explanation :   =COUNTIF(E$1:E$10,E1)&INDEX(D$1:D$10,MATCH(A1,C$1:C$10,0))&","&COUNTIF(E1:E10,E2)&INDEX(D2:D$10,MATCH(A1,C$2:C$10,0))&","&COUNTIF(E1:E10,E2)&INDEX(D3:D$10,MATCH(A1,C$2:C$10,0))&","&COUNTIF(E1:E10,E2)&INDEX(D4:D$10,MATCH(A1,C$2:C$10,0)). Hopefully this will help you with a start in the right direction. You may have to adjust the formula if you want to fill down the A column.